# Create and Insert an Input on "Enter"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create and insert an input(b) below another input(a) on "Enter" of input(a), while also inserting the value of input(a) into input(b).

Javascript

```
function add_name(ele) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<input id='person_holder' type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
        counter++;
        var personName = document.getElementById("people").value;
        document.getElementById('person_holder').value= personName;      
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="add_name" onkeydown="add_name(this)" name="myInputs[]" id="people"/>
</form>
```

Comment: where is `divName` being set?

Comment: The only thing that will be passed to your Event handling function is the Event Object, which will overwrite your `this` argument. You should wrap your function in another function, so you can have another argument for `this` on the internal function. An Anonymous function will do. `return false;` to prevent the normal behavior when `EventObject.keyCode === 13`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your complete code, then I think the problem results from the default behavior of input text box in form. For a input text box in form, when it's focused and enter button is pressed, the form will be submitted, meaning the page will be reloaded. To prevent this, you can add `event.preventDefault();`. Here's the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/34ps5bm3/).